# My Minecraft Map doesn't show up on Single Player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I downloaded a Minecraft map called the Escher Dimension. It is a CTM map. It was in the saves, but it did not show up in Minecraft. It was unzipped. I went inside it to fix the level.dat file, but there was not any file of that name. But there was a data file. What should I do?

Comment: From the site: "Note that this map comes in datapack form. Installation instructions are in the README.md file and in the trailer."

Comment: @SF. That's an answer, please post it as such :)

Comment: @Joachim That's where the answer is.

Comment: @SF. Indeed. Which is an answer by itself.

Comment: To the close voters, this is not modded Minecraft because it involves data packs and data packs are not mods.

Answer (score 1):

From the [site](https://www.minecraftmaps.com/ctm-maps/the-escher-dimension):

> Note that this map comes in datapack form. Installation instructions are in the README.md file and in the trailer.

I've included the contents of the README below.

Download the datapack [here](https://github.com/Zungrysoft/The-Escher-Dimension/releases).

Run the datapack with the following steps:

- Open the "Create New World" menu in Minecraft Java Edition 1.16.5
- Click the "Datapacks" button
- Drag the downloaded zip file into the game menu
- Click on the arrow on the datapack to enable it. (It should be on the right-hand side of the screen.)
- Click "Done", select your difficulty, and create the world
- When it gives you the warning about experimental settings, click "Proceed"
- Wait for the first set of dungeons to generate and begin playing!

If you want to update the datapack to the latest version:

- Open up the the world file you created in the above steps. (This is usually found under %appdata%/.minecraft/saves)
- Open the "datapacks" folder
- Delete the zip file that is there and replace it with the newly-downloaded zip file